# What does this mod rewrite do in htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a little ht code , i just want to

Know what does this code do exactly ?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !robots.txt
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 1st rule does `www` removal from your URL
2. 2nd rule skips rewrite for `/index.php`
3. 3rd rule rewrites all URIs except `/public` and `/robots.txt` to `/index.php`

#### References:

#### 1. [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### 2. [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)